# Can Sphinx be implemented with a CDN?

Tags: sphinx, cdn

Is there any way and/or benefit to utilizing a `CDN` (`Content Delivery Network` e.g. `Cloudflare` or `Incapsula`) with `Sphinx`? I'm utilizing `Sphinx` as part of an auto-complete tool which stores selections from a table in a sphinx index served by a `YUI` Autocomplete which is experiencing some delays in certain scenarios (locale, traffic, mobile) and wonder if utilizing a CDN is feasible, possible and/or beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Well a CDN typically caches responses.

So the CDN could theoretically cache search results too.

Been awhile since used YUI Autocomplete - but guessing its making 'AJAX' requests back to the server to run the queries. You might just need to make some tweaks to the setup to make sure the requests CAN be cached. (eg jQuery adds random params to many AJAX rquests, delibereatly to bust caches!, so would have to specifically disable those settings. Maybe YUI has something similar??? )